# What is causing these elements to have a set height?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/NK3pe/49/

See those white dots inside `#display`? They have the following attributes set to them:

```
left: 10px;
font-size: 31px;
top: 0px;
position: relative;
```

So why aren't the white dots bang at the top of the `#display`? Changing the font size doesn't help. Each span has no margin to padding, but it appears to have some sort of height from somewhere...

The effect I want to achieve is for those white dots to be bang at the top of `#display`, because this is what I'd expect `top: 0px` to do...

Comment: What is the purpose of what you are doing? I see you are using the inline element <span> with a period "." which runs into issues with spacing in and of itself seeing that it is mostly empty space unlike a piece of text like "A".

Answer (score 1):

You can change the line-height.

```
#display{
 line-height:0px;
}
```

Comment: That's better, thanks. There's still some slight height. Is that coming from empty space in the `.` glyph?

Comment: More than likely. If you want better precision than that, maybe you should use something like this Unicode character instead: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2B24/index.htm It looks like it runs baseline to capline. Then just set the font size much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying this, instead of using a glyph like that set your span to

```
 display:inline-block;
 height:2px;
 width:2px;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
```

now that you have a blockish type element positioning it will be much easier.

I checked your JS as well, you will want to remove the left:0px and the font-size adjustments from the script or else you will get the items in all sorts of different rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try rotating the "." character, so it will be closer to the top.

In your javascript:

```
$('#display').append("<span class='" + particleClass + " rotate'> . </span>");
```

And in your css:

```
.rotate
{
  display: block;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```

You may also need to adjust the width to get the rotation to show up correctly.

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Since noone else cares to answer your question, i will have a go at it. Your font-size is causing your dots placements. It's a punctuation character and it has always been at the bottom of any text i ever read.

You could use an image instead, your element is exactly where you expect at to be, but characters don't float to the top of your line and there's no css trick in any books to make them do that.

If you're doing an animated timeline, consider drawing them onto a canvas element or add svg elements for each dot. That allows for better size handling and placement.

Answer (score 0):

Some great answers from people, and thanks for explaining, but I found Ben Dyer's comment was the most helpful. That is, using the code `&#149;` to create a bullet point: ' • '.

While this bullet point glyph contains empty space, it contains the same amount of empty space above and below it, meaning it's easier and less confusing to position than a fullstop, that has most of its empty space above it.

Setting the line height to 0 also helps greatly.